# Editing the previous commit messages in Git using GUI

Tags: git, user-interface, bitbucket, git-gui

I am using bitbucket as my git hosting service. In my repository, i have very old histories and its commit message. Now i need to modify some commit messages.

So is it possible to edit the previous commit messages which is not the latest one using some Git GUI tool.

I am using the source tree as my GUI tool and i am unable to find the option to edit the previous commit messages.

Is any other GUI available to edit the previous commit messages ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The commit message is a part of the commit itself, so changing the commit message of a past commit is equivalent to rebasing the branch starting with that commit. That's something that should be done with caution, and you probably shouldn't be doing it for something as trivial as changing the commit message. Git notes (see git-notes(1)) might be a better fit if you often want to change commit-related metadata.

Comment: Are you using SourceTree for Windows or Mac? Are you open to editing the commits from the command line instead of through a GUI?